# mongodump hangs when using --uri parameter

Tags: mongodb

I am either misusing mongodump or it has a bug, but I'm not sure which. I typically use mongo connection strings in my applications and scripts, e.g.

`mongo mongodb://username:ps@myhostname/dbname` this works

The mongodump tool supposedly supports URL strings, but every time I try to use it it starts and then does nothing:

`mongodump --uri mongodb://username:ps@myhostname/dbname` this runs but stops and does nothing with no CPU usage.

I've tried using `-vvvvv` and there is no interesting data shown.

If I do the exact same thing using the "old" parameters, it works, but then I'd have to parse URIs and that makes me sad:

`mongodump --host myhostname --username username --password ps -d dbname` this works

1) Am I doing this wrong?
2) If this is a bug, where would I file a ticket?
3) Is there a tool that would parse a mongodb:// URI back into pieces so that I can keep using URIs in my automation stack?

`$ mongodump --version
mongodump version: r3.6.8
git version: 6bc9ed599c3fa164703346a22bad17e33fa913e4
Go version: go1.8.5
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017`

`db.version()` in a connected shell also returns 3.6.8

Comment: More information please. `mongodump --version` and `db.version()` reported from connecting to the MongoDB instance you are attempting to connect to. Also note when using `--uri` that the `/dbname` part actually refers to the "database to authenticate against" and **NOT** the database you want to "dump" from.

Comment: I've updated the question with version information. Although I'm surprised: I thought that the /dbname was the database you want to dump from, and you'd have to pass ?authSource=otherdb to pass credentials for another database.

In any case, the database I want to dump and the database I want to authenticate against are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue, and likewise, was quite sad. However, I'm happy again because I realized you MUST append the following two options to your connection string:

`?ssl=true&authSource=admin`

Pop those bad boys on your uri and you should be smooth sailing.

Comment: i used those bad boys it outputs nothing and no directory created there! what is wrong? the command is <mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://user:pass@www.example.com/test?ssl=true&authSource=admin">